# How to fix mismatch between kernel and kernel-devel versions in fedora?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, fedora

I have this preferences:

```
# yum info kernel|grep -E "Name|Version|Release"
Name        : kernel
Version     : 3.13.6
Release     : 200.fc20


# yum info kernel-devel
Installed Packages
Name        : kernel-devel
Arch        : i686
Version     : 3.11.10
Release     : 301.fc20
Size        : 31 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : fedora
Summary     : Development package for building kernel modules to match the
            : kernel
URL         : http://www.kernel.org/
License     : GPLv2 and Redistributable, no modification permitted
Description : This package provides kernel headers and makefiles sufficient to
            : build modules against the kernel package.

Name        : kernel-devel
Arch        : i686
Version     : 3.13.6
Release     : 200.fc20
Size        : 31 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : updates
Summary     : Development package for building kernel modules to match the
            : kernel
URL         : http://www.kernel.org/
License     : GPLv2 and Redistributable, no modification permitted
Description : This package provides kernel headers and makefiles sufficient to
            : build modules against the kernel package.

# uname -r
3.11.10-301.fc20.i686+PAE
```

All installed packages:

```
#rpm -qa | grep ^kernel
kernel-devel-3.13.6-200.fc20.i686
kernel-devel-3.11.10-301.fc20.i686
kernel-PAE-devel-3.11.10-301.fc20.i686
kernel-PAE-3.11.10-301.fc20.i686
kernel-headers-3.13.6-200.fc20.i686
```

When I try to install `some_package.rpm` it says that kernel and kernel-devel versions are different.
How it could be fixed?

Comment: After `yum update`, and a reboot (to use the latest kernel) how does it work?  BTW, why are trying to install `rpm` when you already have it?

Comment: @rickhg12hs sorry, I wanted to say rpm package. When I reboot it is still using old 3.11 kernel

Comment: Curious, `kernel-PAE-3.13.6-200.fc20.i686.rpm` is available from the repos.  It is not installed with `yum update`?  What's the output of `uname -a`?  Is `some_package.rpm` not from a Fedora repo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this to have the kernel devel version the same as your kernel version:

```
sudo yum install "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"
```